# How to run a macro only if the Excel workbook is open with VBScript?

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript, automation

World!

I am trying to automate a report task at my job and I have the following situation:

I need to execute a macro on a workbook by using a script. I tried to write a vbscript to do the job, and  this is the significant part of it:

```
Set objWbk = GetObject("***Path***\test.xlsm")

objWbk.Application.Run "test.xlsm!test" 

WScript.Quit
```

The macro runs perfectly. My real problem is that I only want to do the report only if the workbook is open.

Is there a way (in vbs or vba) to determine if that workbook is open ? (by the way, it is located on another computer on my network)

Comment: Do you want to run the macro if the workbook was already opened? Or do you want to run the macro after `GetObject()` finished opening the workbook?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Only if the workbook is already open

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to run the macro only when the workbook is already opened, something like this might work:

```
wbName = "test.xlsm"
wbFullName = "***Path***\" & wbName

Set xl = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
For Each wb In xl.Workbooks
  If LCase(wb.Path & "\" & wb.Name) = wbFullName Then
    wb.Application.Run wbName & "!test"
  End If
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not fully tested and may a need a bit of modification but see if it gets you what you need.

```
On Error Resume Next
Set objWbk = GetObject("***Path***\test.xlsm")

If Err.Number = 0 Then objWbk.Application.Run "test.xlsm!test" 

wScript.Quit
```